# Laravel eloquent get all if variable is null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a model User and i want search user by city but if the city varible is null a want all user

my code like this

```
User::where('city', $city)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

but if the city varible is null the query return nothing

i thy this

```
 User::doesntHave('city')->get();
```

and this

```
User::whereHas('city')->get();
```

I know i can read my code like this

```
  if($city){
     User::where('city', $city)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
  } else {
    User::orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
}
```

but a want add other varible in my query and is not perfect

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** You could use [`where()` closure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping):

```
User::where(function ($q) use($city) {
    if ($city) {
        $q->where('city', $city);
    }
})->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

**2.** You could use [`when()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#conditional-clauses):

```
User::when($city, function ($q) use ($city) {
    return $q->where('city', $city);
})->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
```

**3.** Do this:

```
$users = User::orderBy('created_at');

if ($city) {
    $users = $users->where('city', $city);
}

$users = $users->paginate(10);
```