# Filter by time multiple methods based on filter params

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I do have those three methods that return some data on my admin dashboard. They work correctly. However the client wants to have some filter by time.

So I do have some parameters that are being sent from vuejs to backend like:

```
filterByPeriod: {

   from:YYYY-MM-DD,
   to:  YYYY-MM-DD

}
```

And I can get those params through request class, my question is how can I filter those methods based on time

```
private function getReservationSources()
{
        return Reservations::where('user_id', request('user_id')
            ->leftJoin('tracking_codes', 'form_submissions.tracking_code_id', '=', 'tracking_codes.id')
            ->leftJoin('tracking_sources', 'tracking_sources.id', '=', 'tracking_codes.tracking_source_id')
            ->select(DB::raw("count(form_submissions.id) as value, tracking_sources.name as name"))
            ->groupBy('tracking_sources.name')
            ->orderBy('value', 'desc')
            ->get();

}

private function getReservationTrackingCodes()
{

        return Reservations::where('user_id', request('user_id')
            ->leftJoin('tracking_codes', 'form_submissions.tracking_code_id', 'tracking_codes.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(tracking_codes.id) as value, tracking_codes.label as name'))
            ->groupBy('tracking_codes.label')
            ->orderBy('value', 'desc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();

}

private function getReservationReferrers()
{

    return Reservations::where('user_id', request('user_id')
        ->select(DB::raw("count(form_submissions.id) as value, form_submissions.referrer as name"))
        ->groupBy('form_submissions.referrer')
        ->orderBy('value', 'desc')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `whereBetween()` method:

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::parse($request->from), Carbon::parse($request->to)])
```

Comment: what if the user doesnt want to filter ? Carbon::parse(null) ? ?

Comment: @PrStandup if dates are `null`, add check using `when()` method, or `where()` closure. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48027941/1227923) for three different working solutions.

Comment: created_at has ambigious meaning,

Comment: @PrStandup it's an example, just change it to column name you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see all the methods are pulling from the same model, so what you could do its pull the model in another method:

```
private function getReseravtions(){

 $builder = Reservations::where('user_id', request('user_id');

 return $this->filterByPeriod($builder);

}
```

So first you just build the eloquent builder without executing the query and sent that through another filter method:

```
 private function filterByPeriod(Builder $builder)
 {
  if(empty(request('filterByPeriod')){

      return $builder;
  }

  $period = json_decode(request('filterByPeriod'));

  if($period->from)
  {

     $builder->where('reservations.created_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($period->from)->startOfDay());
  }

  if ($period->to) 
  {

    $builder->where("reservations.created_at", "<=", Carbon::parse($period->to)->endOfDay());
  }

  return $builder;
}
```

Then simply in the methods call the reservations like this

```
private function getReservationReferrers()
{

        return $this->getReservations()
            ->select(DB::raw("count(form_submissions.id) as value, form_submissions.referrer as name"))
            ->groupBy('form_submissions.referrer')
            ->orderBy('value', 'desc')
            ->take(10)
            ->get();
 }
```

If you have some filtering applied it will filter based on start of dat and end of day carbon instances. If not then simply it will return unfiltered builder and keep going.

Since I am Injecting the builder, have in mind that the builder its an eloquent builder and not a query builder instance so use it at the top

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```